# Global Handlebars template returns a gibberish HTML in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-helper

I was trying to use the meteor's handlebars helper to include a template. Like, my `index.html` looks like

```
<body>
  {{> body}}
</body>

<template name="body">
  {{include "myTemplate" attr=value}}
</template>
```

For this I have created a handlebars helper as follows

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('include', function(templateName, options) {
  return Template[templateName]({name: 'stackoverflow'});
});
```

`myTemplate.html` would look like

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  Hello {{name}}
</template>
```

I don't have `{{> myTemplate}}` anywhere. My plan is to dynamically inject/render it.

So when I run project, the `{{include ...}}` is replaced with some gibberish html like below.

```
<$label:RjH4gQSmtStAKKaBv><$data:yBKwgoiiHFTKfMec2>
<$landmark:uRZQ3PShZEQwKngFG><$events:WW5fKkc6G5FYKzNrb>
<$watch:GQg4oHk9CyhMw97v4><$isolate:5gXzmhnr9ZCWtWjTB>Hello stackoverflow</$isolate:5gXzmhnr9ZCWtWjTB>
</$watch:GQg4oHk9CyhMw97v4></$events:WW5fKkc6G5FYKzNrb>
</$landmark:uRZQ3PShZEQwKngFG></$data:yBKwgoiiHFTKfMec2>
</$label:RjH4gQSmtStAKKaBv>
```

Looks like something to do with spark. When I run `Template.myTemplate({name: 'stackoverflow'})` in the dev console, I get proper string `'Hello stackoverflow'`. I am confused as to why is it giving this gibberish data when used inside a helper?

Comment: First of all, you should avoid having a template named `body`. In the new templating engine (which you can use now with `meteor --release template-engine-preview-10.1`), the body is its own special template accessed by `UI.body`. Second, why are you making a helper that includes a template? That's what `{{> templateName}}` already does. I feel like whatever you're trying to do would be better accomplished by routing with [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to render a template with a helper, you either need to tell Meteor not to escape the string. If it's escaped, Spark won't render it. This is a useful default feature that prevents arbitrary code from being injected into your site, and generally makes it clear what's being rendered.

To do this, you can either write it in triple brackets in the template

```
<template name="body">
  {{{include "myTemplate" attr=value}}}
</template>
```

or return a `SafeString` in the helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('include', function(templateName, options) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(Template[templateName]({name: 'stackoverflow'}));
});
```

On a related note, the [Meteor handlebars documentation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Handlebars#reserved-helper-names) notes that a few helper names are reserved. It doesn't appear that `include` is one of them, but you should be careful using names that sound like keywords.

Comment: Thanks @andrew. .. your first part of the solution (i.e using {{{ }}}) works... but somehow could not get the second part to work. Handlebars.SafeString() is returning null. Something might be wrong in my project. Will dig into it.

Comment: @Goje87 are you sure that you're using `new Handlebars.SafeString` instead of just `Handlebars.SafeString`?